# NumPy: Uniformly distributed N-dimensional samples

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have a list of ranges (in a form of lower bound and upper bound, inclusive) `ranges = [(lb1, ub1), (lb2, ub2)...]` and a positive number `k`. Is there some way how to sample `k` N-dimensional vectors (N is given by `len(ranges)`) from the N-dimensional interval given by `ranges` such that the samples cover the interval as evenly as possible?

I have no definiton of *evenly*, it's just intuitive (maybe that the distances between "neighboring" points are similar). I'm not looking for a precise algorithm (which is not possible without the definition) but rather for ideas of how to do that and that are nice in python/numpy.

I'm (probably) not looking for just random sampling which could very easily create unwanted clusters of samples, but the algorithm can definitely be stochastic.

Comment: `I'm (probably) not looking for just random sampling which could very easily create unwanted clusters` - I don't know what problem you are solving, but to overcome this problem, isn't it easier to just increase the sampling size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the points are independent, then there should be clusters. So, you want the points not to be independent. You want something like a [low discrepancy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) in N dimensions. One type of low discrepancy sequence in N dimensions is a [Sobol sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence). These were designed for high dimensional numerical integration, and are suitable for many but not all purposes.

[image: By_Jheald_http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sobol_sequence_2D.svg]